# How do I get ISO8601 string with time offset in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I want to get a time string in

> "%Y%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

format in chrome using JavaScript. But chrome just returns  'Z' character like below.

```
new Date().toISOString()
->"2015-07-23T07:41:36.617Z"
```

Although I know an upper result is valid, my project also includes a c++ application. So I want to unify date format like below.

```
2015-07-23T16:41:36.617+09:00
```

So are there any good ways to realize my date format?

ES6 specification

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415677/7598333)

Answer (score 1):

> So are there any good ways to realize my date format?

If you want an ISO-8601 version in local time with offset, all you can do is use the non-UTC versions of `getDay`, `getMonth`, etc., get the timezone offset from [`getTimezoneOffset`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26), and build the string yourself. (Or use a library like MomentJS.) There's nothing in the spec that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If there’s a good way depends. Fact is, there is no built-in method for that. But you can build one on your own by using [`Date.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) and doing some [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder). Here’s a lead:

```
// set up date 2009-02-13T23:31:30.123Z (equivalent to 1234567890123 milliseconds):
var localDate = new Date(1234567890123);
// get local time offset, like -120 minutes for CEST (UTC+02:00):
var offsetUTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
// set date to local time:
localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - offsetUTC);
offsetUTC = {
    // positive sign unless offset is at least -00:30 minutes:
    "s": offsetUTC < 30 ? '+' : '-',
    // local time offset in unsigned hours:
    "h": Math.floor(Math.abs(offsetUTC) / 60),
    // local time offset minutes in unsigned integers:
    "m": ~~Math.abs(offsetUTC) % 60
};
offsetUTC = offsetUTC.s + // explicit offset sign
            // unsigned hours in HH, dividing colon:
            ('0'+Math.abs(offsetUTC.h)+':').slice(-3) +
            // minutes are represented as either 00 or 30:
            ('0'+(offsetUTC.m < 30 ? 0 : 30)).slice(-2);

localDate = localDate.toISOString().replace('Z',offsetUTC);
// === "2009-02-13T23:31:30.123+02:00" (if your timezone is CEST)
```

Or a little less verbose:

```
localDate = localDate.toISOString().replace('Z',(offsetUTC<30?'+':'-')+
            ('0'+Math.floor(Math.abs(offsetUTC)/60)+':').slice(-3)+
            ('0'+((~~Math.abs(offsetUTC)%60)<30?0:30)).slice(-2));
```

Note that…

- There’s only a [limited range of UTC time offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets).
- An offset of zero (equivalent to `Z`) must not be represented with a minus sign.
- Both trailing `Z` and numeric offsets are [valid ISO 8601 date times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).
- If you don’t like using your own implementation, try library methods like [Moment.js `format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) or [Datejs `getUTCOffset()`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#getUTCOffset).