# Want to initialise "min" attribute of input type="date" in HTML5 having date value in specific date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have date with specific date format mentioned bellow.

Date_received = `Tue Apr 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I'm getting this value using `HTML5` input type="date" datepicker. I want to initialise the following 'min' attribute.

`<input type="date" id="endDate" ng-model="user.endDate" min="" required />`

I'm using

`var startDate = new Date(Date_received).toISOString().split('T')[0];
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#endDate' ) );
myEl.attr('min',startDate);`

But this(`new Date(Date_received).toISOString()`) sets the value of startDate one day before the actual date. i.e. in this example it sets value of `startDate = 2016-04-04T18:30:00.000Z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular's `$filter` service. Inject it in your `controller` / `directive`

JS:

```
scope.startDate = startDateReceivedFromBackend;
scope.minDate = $filter('date')(scope.startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

See different formats here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="endDate" ng-model="user.endDate" min="minDate" required />
```

Comment: I used the following code and it worked                                                       `var minDate = $filter('date')($scope.user.startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#endDate' ) );
myEl.attr('min',minDate);`      Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's the same value, but toISOString() outputs your value for the UTC timezone.

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20160405T00&p1=54&p2=0

If you want to output the same format as the "ISO" but for the locale time zone, you should look at this solution:

[How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)