# getHours() with time format 2016-04-29T19:00:00

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-format

I'm receiving a time string from an AJAX call to the EventBrite API that looks like: `2016-04-29T19:00:00`

I've got a JS function that parses out the month, day, and year just fine, but the `getHours()` method is returning `12:00:00` (from the date string above).
Code:

```
eventStart = data.events[i].start.local; //looping through events array returned by api
startTime = new Date(eventStart);
eventMonth = month[startTime.getMonth()]; // works
eventDay = startTime.getDate();          //works
eventHour = startTime.getHours();        //returns 12:00:00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Your time string does not have time zone information, so JavaScript assumes it's UTC (GMT). When you call `.getHours()` it gives you the hours in *your* local time zone. If you were to call `getUTCHours()` you'd get 19.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: getUTCHours still gets transformed to client side timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely stemming from the timezone offset. I'm assuming you're in the Pacific timezone, guessing form the -7h difference. It's attempting to give you a converted UTC timestamp when you call `getHours()`, since the timestamp doesn't provide any timezone offset information.

Instead, you can call `getUTCHours()`, which will give you the hours without the timezone offset.

```
var d = new Date('2016-04-29T19:00:00');
d.getHours(); // 12
d.getUTCHours(); // 19
```

Alternatively, you can include the timezone offset in the date string, which is probably the better choice if you want to allow for some automatic localization.

E.g.

```
var ds = '2016-04-29T19:00:00';
var d = new Date(ds + '-07:00');
d.getHours(); // 19
d.getUTCHours(); // 2, since UTC is 7 hours ahead, the full date would be 2016-04-30T02:00:00Z
```

Or more reliably, use `getTimezoneOffset`, although this may cause some surprising results if you're using this on a server/client that's not located in the same timezone as the event. (E.g., sever returns time based on `UTC-07:00`, client recieves that date, and adds its local timezone offset of `UTC-04:00`. This can actually be done by just calling `setMinutes()`, and adding the current minutes, and the timezone offset, since JavaScript's date parsing can handle overflowing dates (setting minutes to 300 would automatically roll up the hours as needed).

E.g.

```
var d = new Date('2016-04-29T19:00:00');
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
d.getHours(); // 19
d.getUTCHours(); // 2
```