# Troubleshoot converting string date to date object.

Tags: javascript

I get from data base this date string:

```
var MeasureDateStr = "2016-07-19T16:29:31";
```

On client I create datetime javascript object from MeasureDate value:

```
var measureDate = new Date(MeasureDateStr);
```

After the  measureDate object is created the content is:

```
var measureDate = Tue Jul 19 2016 19:29:31 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time);
```

As you can see I have different time (+3 hours) relatively to original date string.

My question is why I get diffrent time in measureDate  and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You get user local time because you don't have anything to tell browser in which timezone to look at.

If you want to have UTC time, just add Z at the end of time string:

```
var MeasureDateStr = "2016-07-19T16:29:31Z";
```

Also this may help:
[How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: I stilll get +3 hours

Answer (score 0):

It's because your browsers timezone is set to GMT+3. And since you do not specify a timezone in your datestring it will add 3 hours automatically.

EDIT:

```
var d = '2016-07-19T16:29:31';
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; // get Timezone offset in milliseconds.
d = new Date(Date.parse(d) + offset) // Remove the timezone offset.

console.log(typeof d); // object
console.log(d); // Tue Jul 19 2016 16:29:31 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Old answer:

```
new Date('2016-07-19T16:29:31').toUTCString()
```

Comment: I need a object and not string

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?
The string you are reporting is a local time string.

If I run your example, I get a `Tue Jul 19 2016 16:29:31 GMT+0200 (ora solare Europa occidentale)`, so the *local* time is preserved, while a time zone is attached.

If you add a `Z`, or a time zone indication (like `2016-07-19T16:29:31+03:00`), you can specify exactly the behaviour you want.

Please note that when you log the date, you will always get a local format, even if the date was specified with another time zone:

```
var MeasureDateStr = "2016-07-19T16:29:31+03:00";
var measureDate = new Date(MeasureDateStr); 
console.log(measureDate);
```

I get `Tue Jul 19 2016 15:29:31 GMT+0200 (ora solare Europa occidentale)` because I'm on GMT+2. But the time is converted accordingly.