# Converting Date() to IsoString doesn't show correct hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, date, data-conversion, isodate

i have a date variable like this const date=new Date() and when i console.log this it shows me Tue May 02 2017 11:35:50 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time) which is correct of course. I want to convert this to Iso Date and i'm using toIsoString() function of javascript like this:

```
const IsoDate = (date.toISOString()).slice(0, -5);
      console.log(IsoDate)
```

but it shows me in the console this:
2017-05-02T08:35:50 It seems that it shows 3 hours before the actual date. Why is this happening?

Comment: have you considered using moment.js? gives you tons of date formats and manipulations.

Comment: It's a restriction of my project unfortunately i can't use moment

Comment: This question already has an answer here [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use *toISOString* but get the current date in your timezone, you can adjust the UTC minutes by your offset first, then add the timezone string, e.g.

```js
function toISOStringLocal(date) {
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  var d = new Date(+date);
  var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
  var sign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
  // Subtract offset as ECMAScript offsets are opposite to usual
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
  // Convert offset to string
  offset = ('0' + (offset/60 | 0)).slice(-2) + ('0' + (offset%60)).slice(-2);
  return d.toISOString().replace(/Z\s*/i,'') + sign + offset;
}

console.log('Current date: ' + toISOStringLocal(new Date()));
```

You could also add methods to the Date prototype:

```js
// Return local date in ISO 8601 format
if (!Date.prototype.toISOStringLocal) {
  Date.prototype.toISOStringLocal = function() {
    var d = new Date(+this);
    var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var sign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
    d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
    offset = ('0' + (offset/60 | 0)).slice(-2) + ('0' + (offset%60)).slice(-2);
    return d.toISOString().replace(/Z\s*/i,'') + sign + offset;
  };
}

// Return UTC date in ISO 8601 format
if (!Date.prototype.toISODate) {
  Date.prototype.toISODate = function() {
    return d.toISOString().substr(0,10);
  };
}

var d = new Date();

console.log('The current local date is: ' + d.toISOStringLocal() + 
          '\nThe current UTC date is  : ' + d.toISODate()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it gives time in GMT [Greenwich time zone]. The *toISOString* method is always UTC.

To Get ISO String keeping timezone, use this function

```
    function formatLocalDate() {
//pass date whatever u want
        var now = new Date(),
            tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset(),
            dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-',
            pad = function(num) {
                var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
                return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
            };
        return now.getFullYear() 
            + '-' + pad(now.getMonth()+1)
            + '-' + pad(now.getDate())
            + 'T' + pad(now.getHours())
            + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
            + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds()) 
            + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
            + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
    }
```

Ofcourse Best Option is Moment JS :)

Comment: Nice one thanks. Unfortunately i can't use moment.js

Comment: @user7334203 : then u can use this custom function & Thanks :) you can accept this as answer :p

Comment: "Best" is relative based on some criteria. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting toISOString [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

> ...The timezone is always zero UTC offset...

The timezone is always set to UTC 0. Which is why I'm getting the same value as you as well and I'm in a different time zone.