# Is there any possible way to find the timezone using the ISOtime format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone-offset

localDate: "2020-10-13"
localTime: "20:00:00"
dateTime: "2020-10-14T01:00:00Z"

I have these three datas, how to find the timezone using these data.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You can guess. That's the best you can do.

Comment: how i can guess Mike. Based on hour difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: If you can you get it in real time, then yes. If you mean retroactively, like if you're just given a random time string then there's nothing in a timestamp like that which tells you what timezone it's from

Comment: Based on hour difference we cannot able to find the timezone?

Comment: Is your question how to get the time zone from only those three facts, or how to determine the user’s time zone from the browser? The latter is easy; the former is more challenging.

Comment: By literally guessing. "8pm on the 13th" is the same as "1 am on the 14th but offset by 4 hours", so it's _probably_ UTC-4, but most certainly not _without question_ UTC-4.

Comment: Question is to find the timezone from those three data

Comment: Then you’ll need a lookup table of all of the time zones and the dates and times they changed, for at least the geographical, political, and temporal regions you are interested in. Good luck!

Comment: Mike can you please explain how you are saying UTC-4.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  I think you mean 5 hours.  (UTC-5)

Comment: Of course I do, but given who asked this question, it's disappointing to see you pointing that out rather than user 8171294.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your inputs are exactly as given:

```js
var localDate = "2020-10-13";
var localTime = "20:00:00";
var dateTime = "2020-10-14T01:00:00Z";

var offsetMillis = new Date(localDate + 'T' + localTime + 'Z') - new Date(dateTime);
var offsetHours = offsetMillis / 36e5;
console.log(offsetHours); // -5
```

The result is `-5`, which is 5 hours behind UTC.  This works by creating two date objects, one that is UTC-based, and one that *pretends* to be UTC-based but is actually using the local values.  Subtracting the two yields the offset.

Keep in mind - this is an *offset from UTC*, not a time zone.  One cannot determine the time zone from the offset alone.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more details.

Also keep in mind that not all time zone offsets will be in whole hours.  For example, India uses UTC-5:30, so expect `-5.5` from this code in such a case. (There also exist time zones with 45-minute offsets.)