# offset time zone problem with toIsoString : does not convert well the date object

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, offset, iso

I'm trying to set a date that take the begin of year 2020 with javascript and convert it to isoString; the problem is that always I got a date like this :  like "2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z" !!

```
  start: Date =  new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
```

how to set the date with  this format : "2020-01-01T23:00:01.000Z"

Comment: `Date =  new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 2, 0, 0, 1);` will produce (for your timezone) exactly what you expect

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(\`${new Date().getFullYear()}-01-01T23:00:01.000Z\`))` will produce what you want

Comment: @sahnoun - Your code does not create a `string` at all.  It creates `Date` object.  You may be *seeing* a string representation of that object, but that's not what you are creating here.  Also, the two strings you gave are in the same *format* already.  They are two different points in time, of course.  (`Z` means UTC in ISO 8601 format) .  I could see why you might want `"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000"`, but not sure why you'd want `23:00:01.000Z` - a different time entirely (especially with that 1 second).

Comment: I *think* what you're looking for is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415677/634824), perhaps without the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date produced by `new Date()` makes an allowance for the host timezone offset, the *toISOString* method is UTC so unless the host is set to UTC, there will be a difference equal to the host timezone offset. In the OP that's +01:00.

If you want the start of the year UTC, then you have to first generate a time value as UTC, then use that for the date:

```js
// Get the current UTC year
let year = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
// Create a Date avoiding the local offset
let d = new Date(Date.UTC(year, 0, 1));
// Get a UTC timestamp
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

If, on the otherhand, you want an ISO 8601 timestamp with the local offset rather than UTC, something like 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00, you'll have to do that yourself or use a library (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415677/634824), thanks to [Matt JP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint)), see [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192).