# How to convert this date in a string having this format using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript application and I am finding some difficulties trying to format a date.

So I have a situation like this. I am creating an object like this:

```
returnedEvent = {
  title: eventEl.innerText,
  startTime: returnedEvent.startTime,
  duration: returnedEvent.duration
}
```

As you can see in the previous snippet I have the field:

```
startTime: returnedEvent.startTime,
```

that contains a date object in this format:

```
Mon Feb 20 2017 07:00:00 GMT-0800 (Ora standard del Pacifico USA)
```

Ok but I need to convert this data in a string like this:

```
2017-02-20T07:00:00
```

What could be a smart way to achieve this task and convert the data in the desired string?

Comment: Try `.toISOString().substr(0, 19);`

Comment: ↑ That would shift the time to UTC, so it will be eight hours off in this case. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/ if you need to preserve local time.

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = new Date('Mon Feb 20 2017 07:00:00 GMT-0800 (Ora standard del Pacifico USA)')
console.log(date.toISOString().replace(/\.\d+/, ""))
// Result  2017-02-20T15:00:00Z
let date1 =  new Date('Mon Feb 20 2017 07:00:00 GMT-0800 (Ora standard del Pacifico USA)').toISOString().substr(0, 19)
console.log(date1)
// result 2017-02-20T15:00:00
```