# display hours encompassing its ISO8601 offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm returned a set of ISO8601 dates, along with their offset.
I would like to show the user the hour calculated according to that offset, not the local one. Unfortunately I don't have the timezone, in order to use the `Intl` interface.

An example. Imagine I'm on a etc/GMT+4. If I'm returned this:

```
2019-05-30T07:00:00.000+01:00
```

I want to show the user the following:

```
07:00:00
```

not:

```
10:00
```

Comment: the time according to the specified offset is `7:00` not `8:00` and for GMT+4 it would be `10:00` not `12:00`

Comment: have I misinterpreted the standard? So the time is already compliant with the offset of the string

Comment: The offset at the end indicates the change that has been applied to GMT already, so your example string is equivalent to `2019-05-30T06:00:00.000Z` your best bet is probably to extract the offset from the string before changing to a date since after that the Date always accounts for local machine offset. see: [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: gotcha! Still, I need to show 07:00, not the local time. I'll change the question, thanks.

Comment: I generally like using the native Date object, but for this case [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/) might be simplest. It allows you to keep a date in it's specified offset – from the docs: 'If your date format has a fixed timezone offset, use moment.parseZone: `moment.parseZone("2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00");` ...results in a date with a fixed offset: "2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00"'

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to a library the best option you have presently is:

```js
const input = "2019-05-30T07:00:00.000+01:00";
const localTime = input.substring(11, 19); // assuming you want to truncate milliseconds
console.log(localTime);
```

The reason is that when parsing such as string using the `Date` object, the offset information is *applied*, but then it is discarded.  In other words, all of the following are equivalent:

```js
new Date("2019-05-30T07:00:00.000+01:00")
new Date("2019-05-30T06:00:00.000Z")
new Date(1559196000000)
```

The only thing actually stored within the `Date` object is the value `1559196000000`.  Thus, no amount of manipulating the `Date` object after creating it will be guaranteed to give you back the local hour as it was originally presented in the UTC+1 offset.

Libraries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) and [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) deal with this by retaining the offset and/or original string in a separate internal field.  The `Date` object has no such field.

In the not-too-distant future, JavaScript will be able to handle this natively using the objects and functions proposed by [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/).  For now, you can parse the string manually or use a library.

Comment: Not super fluent in that one, but looks like it can do it with something like: `new spacetime('2019-05-30T07:00:00.000+01:00').format('time-24')` or `new spacetime('2019-05-30T07:00:00.000+01:00').format('{hour-24-pad}:{minute-pad}:{second-pad}')` etc.