# What is this datetime format and how do I convert it with native browser date functions?

Tags: javascript

I have the following date time `2012-05-01T00:00:00T+01:00`

Is this a standard date time format? It seems to have a timezone in the end. So it doesnt seem to be either ISO 8601 or UTC ?

How do I output this in Javascript for todays date ?

Comment: It is in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) format. The `+01:00` is the time offsets from UTC, see also the documentation link.

Comment: `How do I output this in Javascript for todays date ?` ← Do you mean you want this same format for the current date/time?

Comment: @Igor yes please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, JS datetime implementations and string representations vary from browser to browser, so I recommend that instead of relying on those outputs you use a lightweight Date library like Luxon, which allows you to manipulate datetimes and output them in a specific format. https://moment.github.io/luxon/

Answer (score -1):

There are several options for you

```js
let inputFormat = "2012-05-01T00:00:00T+01:00"

let customDateFormat = new Date(sample.split("+")[0].split("T").join(" "))
```

OR best way => moment.js

```
let inputFormat = "2012-05-01T00:00:00T+01:00"

let customDateFormat = moment(sample.split("+")[0].split("T").join(" ")).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```