# Date.getUTCHours() - Different output in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

Given the following code:

```
var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30");
date.getUTCHours();
// Outputs
// Chrome: 15
// Firefox: 18
// IE: 18
```

I'm not sure which date method I should use. `Date.getHours` returns the correct hour in FF and IE, but incorrect in Chrome. And `Date.getUTCHours()` is showing me the correct date, but is not ok in both IE and FF. What are the differences anyway? What UTC date is supposed to be?

I wonder if is there a CrossBrowser native solution... I wouldn't like to use a library for such a simple thing.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the time zone in your Date string? Not sure how it's supposed to be interpreted otherwise according to the standard.

Comment: @aknuds1 And how can I specify the timezone? Is this part of the Date spec? Well, I cannot change the date string anyway, because this is the format I receive from the server.

Comment: If you expect the timezone from the server to be -3 hours, you should append -03:00 to your date string, e.g. `new Date('2014-02-26T15:52:30-03:00').getUTCHours()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome interprets ISO time without Z as UTC; C# issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923932/chrome-interprets-iso-time-without-z-as-utc-c-sharp-issue)

Comment: @Praveen Thanks, that confirms that Chrome is getting it right (yay Chrome).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome interpret your date `var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30");` the same as `var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30Z");` (notice the z, indicating the utc timezone).

FF and IE interpret `var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30");` as being in the timezone of the current user, in my case, it would be `var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30-05:00");` (GMT-0500)

I strongly suggest that you stick with UTC for you computing need and perform the timezone transformation when you want to show the date to the user. Timezone can become a real pain.

Comment: This is what I was going to say, although the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) says that an absent timezone is supposed to be treated as 'Z', so it's strange that FF and IE do it differently.

Comment: Like a boss. I couldn't find that info anywhere. I'll simply add the "Z" to the end of the string to deal with this.

Comment: God damn browsers... Thanks for this :D I did the same, added Z to ensure they all treat it as UTC

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with **`getUTCHours()`** is with your dateString(*`2014-02-26T15:52:30`*).

As per [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), it is better to have either

```
var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30Z");
```

or

```
var date = new Date("2014-02-26T15:52:30+00:00");
```

This ensures common among all browsers.

In your case it is better to have

```
var dateString = "2014-02-26T15:52:30" + "Z";
var date = new Date(dateString);
date.getUTCHours();
```